# Estimating the distribution of frequencies from a sampling of unique values

Tags: distributions, estimation, error, frequency

Let $L$ be a list of elements with repetitions, and $S$ be the set of elements appearing in $L$. I have two tools at my disposal:

1. I have a sample of $k$ elements taken uniformly in $S$, and for each of those elements $e_i$, I can know exactly how many times it appears in $L$ (let's call this frequency $n_i$).
2. I can find an estimation $E$ of the number $N$ of distinct elements in the set (with a relative error of $1/ \sqrt{k}$).

I feel like this gives me an information on the distribution of frequencies in $L$: if all values of $n_i$ are high, then most elements of $L$ must appear several times. This intuition translates into the following estimation: for each element $e_i$ of my sample, I'll say that $E/k$ distinct elements of $S$ appear $n_i$ times.

I have two questions:

1. How can I find the average error between my estimated distribution of frequencies and the actual one? I was thinking of computing the mean squared error, but I don't know whether that is applicable to two vectors which don't have exactly the same number of elements ($E$ is only an estimate of $N$).
2. The distribution I obtain may be inconsistent with the actual number of elements of my list (that I know exactly). Can I make my estimate better by using this information somehow?

I don't have a statistics background, so I'm sorry if I'm not using the right vocabulary, or if some of those questions could have been Googled easily.